# IIS make site viewable over network for WCF app

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, localhost

I made a WCF app that computers on the same network can communicate with.  I have a site with the WCF service hosted on IIS.  How can I make it so the program can work on the other computer(s) so in other words make localhost available to the other computers on the network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was McAfee's firewall...  Well that explains it.

Answer (score 3):

Localhost is allways the local computer.

To access your site from other computers on the network you must use the computer's name instead of localhost.

Note you must make sure that your configuration in web.config also refers to the computer's name.

Comment: It still cant connect on the other computer... Do I need to do something in IIS or with my router?

Comment: try and ping your server from your remote machine

Comment: get a bunch of "request timed out"

Comment: Ok, do I need to do something with my router to allow it to view my pc or something?

Comment: Or my ip like from whatismyip.com?

Comment: turned out to be McAfee firewall, thanks though it helped me get to the solution

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off any firewalls (I.E. Windows Firewall) and attempt the ping again (if this works, figure out which port is being used for your application and open that port specifically if you need the firewall on.)

If you can't ping the server from your remote machine you aren't going to get anywhere with getting your server to respond.

Comment: Going to accept my answer because I posted with answer in the comments of the first question before you posted this.

Comment: Indeed. Looks like I should have typed faster :)